# jQuery/Ajax not working on Azure

Tags: jquery, ajax, azure

I have the exact same code, an HTML MailChimp form, running on two servers.

The first is a LAMP server:

http://flagshippro.com/ourapps/plain.html

The second is hosted on Azure:

https://visitabudhabi.azurewebsites.net/plain.html

Can anybody tell my why the validation is working perfectly on the first server but not the Azure server?

Is there something I need to do to the Azure instance to fix this?

Comment: Please include any relevant code in your question.

Comment: It's blocking mailchimp's validation js because it's pulling from http instead of https. Change all the external files to use https and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the problem is because your code which is running securely in Azure Websites is referencing css and js files over http (i.e. mixed security). This is what I see in developer console in IE when I run the Azure websites URL:

[image]

However if I access the website over http (which is the case in your 1st URL), I don't get that error. Can you access the azure website url over http or change the links to css/js file to use https and see if that makes a difference?

Answer (score -1):

The first step would be to correct the errors that show up in the Firebug console:
[image: Character encoding error, and jQuery is not defined.]